# jQuery Spinner after submitting form data through Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, css

Here is my Jquery code for submitting data and show a spinner

```
    <script>
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $("#VEGAS").submit(function(){
   $('#One').click(function() {
   var routeUrl = "<?= url('/') ?>/vpage";
    alert(routeUrl);
    $.ajax({
        url: routeUrl,
        type: "POST",
        data: form_data +'&jegy=' + test,
        success: function(result) {
            $('#alert').html('successfully added!');
            $('#msg-group').delay(1000).hide('slow');
            $.showLoading(); // here i am loading a spinner
          }
      });
    });
    return false;
});
</script>
```

I have included following libraries using this [link](http://www.jqueryscript.net/loading/jQuery-Plugin-To-Handle-CSS3-Powered-Spinners-Loaders-Loading-js.html)

```
   <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
   <script src="dist/jquery.loading.min.js"></script>
   <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
   <script src="dist/jquery.loading.min.js"></script>
```

But this loading spinner is not working. An error comes to the console

```
    jquery.loading.min.js 404 (Not Found)
```

Can any one tell me about the Jquery spinner because i am using it for the first time

Comment: The script isn't loading... check if the name is write correctly, and if is inside "dist/". Remove the duplicated script call. (you have 2 script src=dist/loading.min)

Comment: i have tried it by removing but still not working

Comment: Do you have a dist folder? If yes, is there a filename in there named jquery.loading.min.js?

Comment: To add: the example in the plugin docs is incorrect, you shouldn't include JavaScript files twice, the first snippet box is for CSS linking.

Comment: If  jquery.loading.min.js not found is a specific problem. Or is not in /dist folder or has another name.

Comment: @FatimahSanni no i hav't

Comment: is dist folder in web server root foler? try <script src="/dist/jquery.loading.min.js"></script>

Comment: That's why. It's looking for the file jquery.loading.min.js inside the dist folder. If it's not there, you have to download and put it in there.

Answer (score -1):

you just use these links

and remove extra links which is related loading libraries.
i sure problem is your in extra scripts.

Comment: <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="dist/jquery.loading.min.js"></script>